# Remap TAB key to another key

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, my TAB key is not working
and I want to use auto complete function.
Is there any way I could assign other key for the
same function in Ubuntu manually? 
I looked into the keyboard layout but I couldn't able
to figure it out, Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For assign certain key to other, you need two tools, already available in ubuntu: `xev` and `xmodmap`

With `xev` you can output some information about the pressed key, or with

```
xmodmap -pke
```

you can read all the configured key, keycode and action.

With `xmodmap` you can change key map.

For example, this command assign tab action to backspace key (keycode 22):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = Tab"
```

to reassign to backspace is natural function, type:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = BackSpace"
```

These change will be lost after reboot. if you want that the changes are always loaded, you must create a file containing the keyboard mapping and load when the session start:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap (create file configuration .Xmodmap in your home directory)
```

then create file `.xinitrc` in your home directory (if not exists) and add this line (or append if file exists):

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

this command loads the configuration at the start of each session.

You can create keyboard shortcuts by installing [AutoKey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/autokey-gtk/) from software center.
After install, run autokey and create new phrase like this:

[image]

the key combination  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>  will emulate the tab key.

Comment: Sorry If i am asking the wrong question, Do I have to place the "Key" in place of TAB to assign the same function ?

Comment: if I understand it, you want to assign the "TAB" key to another: if this is so, you must use the command `xmodmap -e "keycode X = Tab"` with X the keycode of the key you want it to work like the TAB key

Comment: I want a combination of key like Alt+A , so can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Just now I found out that pressing Esc key for a second gives me the same thing, why is that?, moreover it is also suggesting the possibilities.

Comment: i edited my answer.